# Delete list of lists with a condition in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working with *"for"* in python and I need to delete some lists of T if some conditions are met.

```
T=[[0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 4, 8], [0, 2, 5, 8], [0, 2, 5, 11], [0, 2, 6, 11], [0, 3, 5, 8], [0, 3, 5, 11], [0, 3, 6, 10], [0, 3, 6, 11], [0, 3, 8, 10], [0, 4, 6, 10], [0, 4, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7], [1, 3, 5, 11], [1, 3, 6, 10], [1, 3, 6, 11], [1, 3, 7, 10], [1, 4, 6, 9], [1, 4, 6, 10], [1, 4, 7, 9], [1, 4, 7, 10], [1, 5, 7, 9], [1, 5, 9, 11], [1, 6, 9, 11], [2, 4, 6, 9], [2, 4, 7, 8], [2, 4, 7, 9], [2, 5, 7, 8], [2, 5, 7, 9], [2, 5, 9, 11], [2, 6, 9, 11], [3, 5, 7, 8], [3, 7, 8, 10], [4, 7, 8, 10]]
```

Example: delete all the lists where the number 1 appears, then

```
T=[[0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 4, 8], [0, 2, 5, 8], [0, 2, 5, 11], [0, 2, 6, 11], [0, 3, 5, 8], [0, 3, 5, 11], [0, 3, 6, 10], [0, 3, 6, 11], [0, 3, 8, 10], [0, 4, 6, 10], [0, 4, 8, 10], delete([1, 3, 5, 7]), delete([1, 3, 5, 11]), delete([1, 3, 6, 10]), delete([1, 3, 6, 11]), delete([1, 3, 7, 10]), delete[1, 4, 6, 9], delete[1, 4, 6, 10], delete[1, 4, 7, 9], delete[1, 4, 7, 10], delete[1, 5, 7, 9], delete[1, 5, 9, 11], delete[1, 6, 9, 11], [2, 4, 6, 9], [2, 4, 7, 8], [2, 4, 7, 9], [2, 5, 7, 8], [2, 5, 7, 9], [2, 5, 9, 11], [2, 6, 9, 11], [3, 5, 7, 8], [3, 7, 8, 10], [4, 7, 8, 10]]
```

Is there an algorithm or command in python to do it??

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with list comprehesnion:
`[lst for lst in T if 1 not in lst]`

or a for loop:

```
final = []
for lst in T:
    if 1 not in lst:
        final.append(lst)
```

If you're working to learn Python, a list comprehension is a single-line for loop for building lists.

List comprehensions are also generally faster than for loops:

```
def for_loop(T):
    final = []    
    for lst in T:    
        if 1 not in lst:
            final.append(lst)
    return final

def list_comp(T):
    return [lst for lst in T if 1 not in lst]

%timeit for_loop(T)
3.02 µs ± 61.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit list_comp(T)
2.16 µs ± 9.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: @MathYobani Did this answer your question?

Comment: One day I will start using list comprehensions... +1 for reminding me they are faster.